# Библиотека json simple. JSONArray to List<String>. Stream API

Tags: java, json, java-stream

У меня есть json строка, которая представляется собой массив

```
["829390","831690","831700","831510","844310","850950"]
```

Используя библиотеку json simple, я получил JSONArray, после чего, используя stream, попытался получить `List<String>`, но IDEA подчеркнула мой код, жалуясь на некорректность типов (Required: `List<String>` Found: `Object`)

```
String jsonStr = "[\"829390\",\"831690\",\"831700\",\"831510\",\"844310\",\"850950\"]";
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parseWithException(jsonStr);
List<String> ads = jsonArray.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

С чем связано данное поведение?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что [`JSONArray`](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONArray.java) расширяет "сырой" ([raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)) `ArrayList`. Поэтому он наследует "сырой" метод `stream()`, который возвращает "сырой" `Stream`. Типы нестатических методов "сырых" типов "стираются" (erasure), поэтому `collect(..)` возвращает `Object`.

Можно вернуть обобщенные типы, явно приведя результат `stream()`:

```
List<String> ads = ((Stream<?>)jsonArray.stream()).map(Object::toString).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Answer (score 0):

может так будет работать?

```
String jsonStr = "[\"829390\",\"831690\",\"831700\",\"831510\",\"844310\",\"850950\"]";
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try {
        jsonArray = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parseWithException(jsonStr);
        List<String> ads = (List<String>) jsonArray.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (String s:ads) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Да, так работать будет, но интересует именно то, почему не работает мой вариант?

Comment: ну IDEA говорит что 
jsonArray.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList())
это объект

Comment: Да я понимаю, что IDEA говорит ) В это и заключается вопрос, почему там `Object`, а не `List<String>`?

Comment: @AlexeyKononov если посмотреть на сигнатуру общего метода, то мы увидим следующее `<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)`, т. к. метод `collect` может возвращать разные типы. Но в случае, когда для потока тип не указан, вместо всех обобщённых типов T, A, R используется `Object`. А метод как раз возвращает тип R, который в данном случае также является типом `Object`.